# Can a notification for a forground service be shown on Android wear(watch)?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I use `startForeground(int, Notification)` to start my service as foreground service with a notification. While the notification shows on the phone, it doesn't show up on the paired watch.

Using `NotificationManagerCompat` as mentioned on the Android developer site works, but the service is not started in foreground. How to solve this issue?